# Поиск файлов по названию в одной папке и копирование найденных файлов в другую папку

Tags: vb.net

Дали задание на работе по поиску и копированию файлов pdf из одной папки в другую.

Делаю на vb.net.

Есть форма на которой есть:

1. Кнопка которая вызывает folderbrowserdialog и запоминает указанный путь в label1 (папка где нужно искать)
2. Кнопка также вызывает folderbrowserdialog и запоминает указанный путь в label2 (папка где нужно сохранить)
3. textbox1 в который нужно ввести названия файлов. Сами файлы имеют названия типа: 2014-345.pdf. Где 2014 - это год, а 345 - номер. В textbox будут вводить только номера файлов построчно, например вот так:

- 234
- 238
- 345
- и т.д.

Все что описал уже есть, но теперь нужно сделать кнопку при нажатии на которую, эта кнопка возьмет список указанных файлов из textbox1, найдет их в указанной папке путь которой указан в label1 и скопирует в указанную папку путь которой указан в label2 и было бы хорошо если бы она показала какие файлы не удалось найти.

Буду рад любой помощи,

Answer (score 0):

`My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filePath)` - Для проверки наличия файла

`FileSystem.FileCopy(sourcePath, targetPath)` - Для копирования